# Set Application Folder from Custom Action in Visual Studio Setup project

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, deployment, installation

My Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project must choose the install directory automatically based on a configuration file.  I'm using a C# class derived from `Installer` for the custom action.  I read the config file in my `Install()` method.

How do I change the installer's Application Folder from within this custom action?

Comment: Is this by chance a .MSI installer..? you can edit all that info in design time if so..

Comment: The directory is determined by a configuration file on the user's computer at install time, so there's no way I can set it at design time.

Comment: you could still get around this if I am not mistaken by creating a MSI installer application.. but that's your call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation folder path is stored in TARGETDIR property.

Installer class actions cannot set Windows Installer properties, so you cannot use your current custom action to dynamically change the installation path.

Only the following custom action types can set installer properties:

- [win32 DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx) which receives the installation handle
- VBScript and Java Script
- WiX toolset custom action

If you use one of them, you can set the TARGETDIR property to any path you need.

Answer (score 0):

if this is a regular application you can also look at changing and or adding things here
check out the screen shot [image]